# Newton JSON Convert Json To List

Tags: c#, json.net

I've seen some examples on SO already. I followed their examples, but I am not sure why mine's not working.

Here is the code:

```
private void convertData()
{
    //Business logic...

    List<FeedRow> feed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<FeedRow>> (content);
}

public class FeedRow
{
    public string eventPK { get; set;}
    public string picturePK { get; set;}
}
```

Debug shows me that the JSON (variable content) looks like this:

> ["{\"eventPK\":\"321-0321\",\"picturePK\":\"019-5903\"}","{\"eventPK\":\"203-1234\",\"picturePK\":\"013-2034\"}"]

I added a try/catch and the following message was given:

> Error converting value "{"eventPK":"321-0321","picturePK":"019-5903"}" to type 'learning.FeedRow'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 112.

Comment: It looks like content is double encoded. The end result is that JSON.NET sees it as an array of strings rather than an array of `FeedRow`. How do you generate your JSON?

Comment: @mason I am connected to a Web API. In the method of the Web API, the return type is string[]

When I receive it I do:

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: Is the Web API under your control? Seems like this should be what it's generating: `[ {"eventPK":"321-0321", "picturePK":"019-5903"}, {"eventPK":"203-1234", "picturePK":"013-2034"} ]`

Comment: Can you provide some more information regarding your feedrow class

Comment: @Maddy That's not necessary, the class is shown in the question and the issue is obvious.

Comment: @mason you were right; my web api was return an array of strings. So I had to do two deserialization. In my web api, I basically have data that is serialized in my db, and I fetch it and put it directly in the array. The array is then transformed into a string when I receive it. So I have to serialize it first to get the array of strings and then serialize each string into the FeedRow obj

Comment: Why not have your Web API return `List<FeedRow>`? Serving up double encoded data isn't very clean.

Comment: @mason You're right. I'll do that!

Comment: The FeedRow objects that are stored in the database, do you store them as JSON? It's probably better to store them as as a real database table with separate columns for the EventPK and PicturePK. That cuts down on the amount of serialization and deserialization you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `content` is being parsed as an array of strings, see double quotes immediately after [ and before ].

EDIT after reading OP's comment about string[] return type:
NewtonJSON will/can not automatically convert a string[] to a FeedRow object with two attributes.

Two options that I would try are:
1. Alter the Web API to return JSON object[] instead of string[]
2. Loop through the strings of `content` (if it is, indeed, a string[]) and use NewtonJSON to convert each string to a FeedRow object and add to a List.

Comment: There are also redundant quotes in the middle of the string.

Comment: Not redundant, but yes the ones in the middle (and the comma) signify that content is being parsed as an array of strings.